whisper finetuning on mutiple gpu's
Actually i am  fine tuning  whisper model but  its  running  on  only  one gpu and other 3 gpu remain idle.
Problme is that it is not utilizing the other 3 GPU
I want to fine tuning the whisper model on 4 gpu on audio dataset and
DESCRIPTION OF GPU:
4 NVIDIA RTX A4000 GPUs with the following configuration:
Memory: 16 GB (GDDR6) per GPU
CUDA Cores: 6144 cores per GPU
Tensor Cores: For AI acceleration, ideal for tasks like deep learning.
Memory Interface: 192-bit
Memory Bandwidth: 624 GB/s
Architecture: Ampere
TDP: 140 Watts per GPU
Total System RAM: 128 GB

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
